# What is this SMD component? (Fuse?)

Tags: surface-mount

This part with a "B1" on it is in series between a FET and it's load, I'm trying to figure out what it is.  This is on a e-bike display that should get up to 85V.

While I don't know if it is normal (this unit has failed), these components measure 0 ohms.

[image: Unknown Part]

Comment: Is there not a reference designator for that part silkscreened onto the board?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the PWR silkscreen is for the wire, and there is nothing else around it.

Comment: there is actually a similar marking for a fuse on ebay on the following link 

"https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2Fitm%2F10PCS-B1250T-FUSE-TELECOM-1-25A-600V-SMD-B1250-1250-1250T-%2F192826547817&psig=AOvVaw2BgSZpAhJyFDoOnRru1xSX&ust=1600477658515000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCNjJ3-rB8esCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD"

Comment: And this picture too from google which has a similar B6 fuse on it 

"https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H30e213d6fc694adc955ae9e121724e04d/uxcell-One-Time-font-b-1210-b-font-font-b-SMD-b-font-font-b-Fuse.jpg" 

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Thank you.  I will assume it is a fuse until I find otherwise.  It's a shame the font isn't the same.

Comment: The 'B' really does not look like the Bourns 'B'. Probably some other obscure brand. If it measures low resistance it's probably okay. And maybe a 1A fuse. Though why they would pick that font for the 1 is hard to fathom.

Comment: https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H99e8fad970964edba5f9aacdcf7a9b0fh/20PCS-Lot-SMD-Resettable-Fuse-1206-350MA-PTC12066V035-750MA-PTC12068V075-SMD-Self-recovery-Fuse.jpg

Comment: A resistor? Can you zoom out a bit?

Comment: The B could be the style of https://www.bourns.com but its hard to tell which fuse it really is. the soldering looks like shi...

Comment: Thank you Bruce, that font is dead on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bruce Abbott found, I believe these are resettable fuses

[image: Example Picture]